# How to reduce an adverbial clause

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence:

> Ms.Cho relayed her concerns about the company's financial situation **while she was having a meeting with the manager**.

My friend reduced it:

> Ms.Cho relayed her concerns about the company's financial situation **having a meeting with the manager**.

I think the word *while* cannot be omitted in this sentence, but he doesn't agree with me.
Is he right?
Please help me! thanks

Comment: What a native speaker would actually say is "She relayed her concerns *during* a meeting with the manager". Shoehorning a present participle into that is possible but a complete red herring, because nobody would ever try that in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think this construction might work:

> **"Ms. Cho relayed her concerns about the company's financial situation, having a meeting with the manager."**

The terminating modifier (present participle phrase) eliminates the need for *while*.

You could also further reduce the sentence so it reads like this:

> **"Ms. Cho relayed her concerns about the company's financial situation, meeting with the manager.**

However, if you use this sentence, you may have to supply further information, such as supplying a specific day or hour for the meeting.

Answer (score 0):

You're right; the 'while' is necessary in this sentence as it stands:

> Ms. Cho relayed her concerns about the company's financial situation
>   while having a meeting with the manager.

The following is possible (Pedanticpoet22's suggestion changes the meaning, implying that the purpose of the meeting was to mention Ms Cho's concerns):

> Having a meeting with the manager, Ms. Cho relayed her concerns about the 
>   company's  financial situation.